# Windows 10: On one monitor static display, on the others multiple desktops

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, multiple-desktop

I'm working on 3 monitors. I am using multiple desktops options at the same time (2, sometimes 3 desktops), so I can view 2x3 (3x3) monitors quickly. Such a solution in my work has many advantages, but also disadvantages. In some extreme situations you can get lost.

I am constantly looking for ways to improve my work.

So, I wonder if there is a way, application which will support something like:

- 1 monitor will be static without the multi-desktop option, always on top
- the other 2 monitors will support the multi-desktop option, so only those will be changing

Comment: You may want to add details about the operating system and the desktop software you are using.

Comment: win 10, i don't use any additional desktop software, just build in windows 10 multi desktop feature